# Search button not working on deployed web application but works locally on testing machine

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on my aspx page with 2 textboxes (Firstname and Lastname) that allows the users to filter the gridview when they click on the "Search" button.

When I run this locally on my dev machine it works perfect.  Once I deployed it to my IIS server...when a user clicks on the search button nothing happens.  I tried to open the page on several differnt computers and the same thing happens on all of them.  I noticed when I load the page from the IIS server itself the search button works.  Any idea what could cause this?

Below is the code for my textboxes, button and filter parameter:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

 <p>
 Last Name:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <br /><br />First Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Search" />

<asp:GridView ID="TDetails" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="PersonID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Details_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="7" >

        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource
                ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                connectionString="Data Source=Server\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY LastName"
                        FilterExpression="[LastName] LIKE '{0}%' AND [FirstName] LIKE '{1}%'">

                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="LastName" ControlID="TextBox3" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="FirstName" ControlID="TextBox4" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Really? *nothing* happens? Does a postback occur? How about a JavaScript error? A network request?

Comment: It does nothing.  I now also discovered it works in Chrome browser on every machine but not I.E. still unsure of the cause...

Comment: Please directly answer each of the questions I posed in my previous comment.

Comment: No postback occurs.  No JavaScript error. No network request.

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You don't have enough code here to reproduce this issue.